# Tailwind CSS background Image not Working with @apply

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, tailwind-css

I am applying background Image with Tailwind. I have separate file for CSS.

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

body {
   @apply bg-[url('./2.PNG')]; 
}
```

This is my code Image is working with background-image property but not with Tailwind.

Comment: What is the error? Is the url to the image wrong when you load the css in your browser? Do you have JIT enabled? Which version of tailwind do you use?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner The `bg-[url('./2.PNG')]` class does not exist. If `bg-[url('./2.PNG')]` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive. This is what I am getting. Path is working fine with plain-css

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer a single of my questions.

Comment: " The bg-[url('./2.PNG')] class does not exist. If bg-[url('./2.PNG')] is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a @layer directive "

This is the error. I don't know what JIT is. Version is 2.2.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you are using `bg-[..]` was only introduced in Tailwind v3.x in combination with their [JIT compiler](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/just-in-time-the-next-generation-of-tailwind-css).

For Tailwind v2.x you can [read up here](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image) on how to implement a background-image properly.

TL;DR:

```
 // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        backgroundImage: {
         'custom-background-image-name': "url('path-to-image/image.png')",
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then use it like so

```
@layer base {
  body {
    @apply bg-custom-background-image-name;
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried use this ( theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
       ''fond_caractères'' : url("fond_caractères.png"),
    },
  },   but Tailwind says  :     The `bg-fond_caractères:` class does not exist. If `bg-fond_caractères:` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.

Answer (score 2):

Try `bg-[image:url('2.PNG')]`.
Without `image:` tailwind does not know whether  the `bg-` is for the background color or for the image.

edit: only works with tailwind v3.x.

Comment: That looks interesting - Mind sharing a link to tailwind documentation where I could read that up? :)

Comment: @PhilippMeissner [Here you go](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#resolving-ambiguities).

Comment: Just realized the questioner wasn't using tailwind v3. In that case, the solution posted by @PhilippMeissner should work.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately even assuming this was an issue for v3.x I can't seem to find anything about adding `image:` anywhere to properly generate the expected class.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner The documentation linked to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Types) MDN doc which is the list of available CSS data types for your usage.